# How to check if any bluetooth device is connected in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth

I've been attempting to detect whether a bluetooth device is connected to an android phone once a button is clicked. If detected, I would like to interact with this device from within my app. The device I'm talking about is http://www.senanetworks.com/sd1000-01.html .

I've used the example code of https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ble-manager to test it out, but unfortunately, it's not picking up this device even though the regular settings app does. Additionally, checking for already connected peripherals does not work if I connected to the device outside of the app. Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device you are using, the Parani-SD1000 Bluetooth Serial Adapter, does state in its specs that it uses Bluetooth 2.0. You are using a library for Bluetooth Low Energy devices, but BLE was only introduced with Bluetooth 4.0.

Your devices definitely uses Bluetooth Classic (also nown as Bluetooth Serial), thats also the reason why it shows up in the settings of your mobile phone. You need to use a library like [react-native-bluetooth-serial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bluetooth-serial). You can use the `isConnected()` method to detect wether or not it is connected.

Comment: Having some trouble reading the device. I'm able to find and connect to the device now, but when I read the device, it comes back empty. I'm a complete newbie with bluetooth, so not sure where I'm going wrong here. I'm not sure if the device is sending data, or I'm not receiving it correctly.

Comment: There are some Serial Bluetooth Terminal Apps available, maybe try one of these before getting into writing your own app. If they work you'll know it's not the devices fault if anything goes wrong with your app ;) You also learn a lot about the data you receive

Comment: Okay, just tried that. Thank you for the suggestion, def seems I can use this app for testing. Not giving me anything back though, so I'm assuming I need to call a function in the bluetooth device to get data back since it does not send automatically. It's a printer with a bluetooth device connected to it. The printer is tm u295 epson

Comment: Just found this page: manualslib.com/manual/419185/Epson-Tm-U295-B-W-Dot-Matrix-Printer.html?page=42#manual about the commands, but no luck sending them using the android app called "Serial Bluetooth Terminal". Tried hex and ASCII values