# Reading data on bluetooth device comes back as empty: react native bluetooth serial

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, bluetooth

Here is a link from my last question about how to connect to a bluetooth classic device. [How to check if any bluetooth device is connected in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70691152/how-to-check-if-any-bluetooth-device-is-connected-in-react-native) I'm now able to connect to the device and the listeners, such as onConnected, onDisconnected, enabled, disabled, all work, but I can't seem to figure out how to read the data from the bluetooth device. The device is this: http://www.senanetworks.com/sd1000-01.html

I've tried this on UseEffect:

```
BluetoothSerial.withDelimiter('\r').then(() => {
        Promise.all([
          BluetoothSerial.isEnabled(),
          BluetoothSerial.list()
        ])
        .then((values) => {
          const [ isEnabled, devices ] = values
          this.setState({ isEnabled, devices })
        })
    
        BluetoothSerial.on('bluetoothEnabled', () => console.log('Bluetooth enabled'))
        BluetoothSerial.on('bluetoothDisabled', () => console.log('Bluetooth disabled'))
        BluetoothSerial.on('read', (data) => {
    
           console.log(`DATA FROM BLUETOOTH: ${data.data}`);
           Toast.show(data.data);
       })
        BluetoothSerial.on('error', (err) => console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`))
        BluetoothSerial.on('connectionLost', () => {
          if (this.state.device) {
            console.log(`Connection to device ${this.state.device.name} has been lost`)
          }
          this.setState({ connected: false })
        })
      });
```

as well as just calling this:

```
BluetoothSerial.readFromDevice().then((data) => console.log(data))
```

The first code block is a listener for data, but it doesn't get any. The second code block is logging nothing, just emptiness. To note, the bluetooth device is connected to this printer: https://epson.com/For-Work/Printers/POS/TM-U295-Slip-Printer/p/C31C163292 and this meter: https://www.lcmeter.com/sites/default/files/EM100-11_%28LCRII%20Setup%20%26%20Operation%29.pdf

Any help will be appreciated. First time working with bluetooth devices.